# save ressources of web page blackberry

Tags: blackberry, web

How can I save all ressources of web page from an url ?
I mean  save the HTML and also automatically to store all associated files (images, CSS files, js files, etc) without display the page on browser field

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java SDK, then open InputStream instance for this file, read this file, parse its contents, open new streams for resources inside of this file and save all files on device memory/micro sd card.

I would prefer micro SD card as file destination. Because free volume of internal device memory is critical for device operating system. And its shortage leads to device malfunction.

Comment: Open input stream for a particular web-page. It is text-file with html directives inside. Parse them, extract path to another resources, open streams to them, read them via these streams and save to the device.

Comment: how can I parse this file I don't know if it is after href,src ... and the end of url...